# Функция slideToogle() работает некорректно в ie

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, explorer

Доброго времени суток.

Я использую на одной из своих страниц функцию `slideToogle()` от jQuery для сворачивания "тела" баннера (остается виден заголовок и footer). Под всеми браузерами работает нормально, но под IE (8, 9) происходит следующее: тело сворачивается и сразу же разворачивается. Вот код, как я его использую:

```
$element.find(".flyout-header, .minimize").click(function () {
    self.toggle();
    return false;
});

toggle = function () {
    this.$e.find(".flyout-body").slideToggle(this.duration);
    this.$e.find(".minimize").toggleClass("minimized");
};
```

Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? В google нашел много проблем с `slideToogle()` и IE, но похожего как у меня - нет. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Вот кусок HTML:

```
<div id="flyout" style="display: none; bottom: 10px; ">

    <div class="flyout-header">
        Subscribe Today
        <div class="minimize">minimize</div>
        <div class="close">close</div>
    </div>

    <div class="flyout-body">
        <a target="_blank" href="%c%u">
           <div class="flyout-ad" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;">
              <img class="cover" alt="" src="" alt="" style="position: absolute;" />
           </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="flyout-bottom"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: можно кусок хтмл кода с .flyout-header, .minimize, .flyout-body. Такое впечатление, что обработчик срабатывает дважды. Я имею ввиду, что ИЕ может немного по другому отображать и обработчик клика вешается на 2 элемента, откуда и мгновенное сворачивание/разворачивание.

Answer (score 3):

То о чем я и говорил:

```
<div class="flyout-header">
        Subscribe Today
        <div class="minimize">minimize</div>
        <div class="close">close</div>
    </div>
```

---

```
$element.find(".flyout-header, .minimize").click(function () {
    self.toggle();
    return false;
});
```

В IE событие клика срабатывает дважды. Первый раз как по элементу flyout-header, второй раз - по элементу minimize. Вот вам и эффект сворачивания/разворачивания. Напишите просто

```
$element.find(".minimize").click(...)
```

Зачем вешать на flyout-header ?

Comment: "Зачем вешать на flyout-header ?" потому что сворачиваться body  должен по нажатие как на minimiize так и по нажатию на flyout-header...
Попробовал исключить по очереди .flyout-header и .minimize из $element.find(".flyout-header, .minimize").click(function () - эффект тот же

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему. Дело в том, что этот баннер рисуется скриптом (рисуется HTML, создается объект (вешаются обработчики) и потом запускается). Для того, чтобы в IE заработал, его нужно было запустить дважды (такой вот прикол). Так вот изначально я вместо того чтобы просто запустить уже созданный объект-баннер я его создавал заново (то есть еще раз вешал обработчик на onClick()). Таким образом получался один HTML с двумя обработчиками onClick(). Как-то так.

Comment: мое предположение было близко к правде ))

Comment: @Vitalii Maslianok - именно Ваше предположение натолкнуло посмотреть как и где я мог повесить два обработчика. Спасибо!